# How to extend class with generics combined with mixins in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, subclass, mixins

**Background**

I want to create the following structure (blue are abstract and green are concrete):

[image]

So I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492002/passing-generic-types-through-to-mixins-in-typescript) and created the following code:

```js
export abstract class BaseResourceModel {
    public id?: string;
}

type ConcreteClass<C> = new (...args: any[]) => C;

export interface IBaseList<T extends BaseResourceModel>
  extends ConcreteClass<BaseList<T>> {
}

export function TableMixin<T extends BaseResourceModel>() {
  return function <B extends IBaseList<T>>(Base: B){
    class Temporary extends Base implements OnInit {
       (...)
    }
    return Temporary;
  };
}

@Component({ template: '' })
export abstract class BaseList<T extends BaseResourceModel>
  implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  (...) 
}

@Component({ template: '' })
export abstract class BaseServerList<T extends BaseResourceModel> extends BaseList<T> {
  (...) 
}
```

**Problem**

I don't know exactly how to create the abstract `BaseServerTable` extended from `BaseServerList` and composed with `TableMixin` keeping the generic `<T extends BaseResourceModel>`on it. I get the following errors:

- First attempt:

```js
class DummyBaseServerList<T> extends BaseServerList<T> { }

@Component({ template: '' })
class BaseServerTable<T> extends TableMixin<BaseResourceModel, typeof DummyBaseServerList>()(BaseServerList<T>) {
  (...)
}
```

Results in: `Expected 1 type arguments, but got 2.ts(2558)`

- Second attempt:

```js
class DummyBaseServerList<T> extends BaseServerList<T> { }

@Component({ template: '' })
class BaseServerTable extends TableMixin<BaseResourceModel>()(DummyBaseServerList) {
  (...)
}
```

Results in: `No base constructor has the specified number of type arguments.ts(2508)`

- Third attempt:

```js
@Component({ template: '' })
class BaseServerTable<T> extends TableMixin<BaseResourceModel>()(BaseServerList<T>) {
  (...)
}
```

Results in: `Value of type 'typeof BaseServerList' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?ts(2348)`

**Question**

How to implement this pattern? What I am missing? I've searched everywhere about samples a pattern like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the syntax you want is this:

```
class BaseServerTable<T> extends
    (TableMixin<BaseResourceModel>()(DummyBaseList))<T> { } // okay
```

---

`TableMixin` is a generic function with exactly one type parameter and no function parameters.  So you have to call it like `TableMixin<BaseResourceModel>()`.  That results in:

```
const TMBRM = TableMixin<BaseResourceModel>();
/* const TMBRM: <B extends IBaseList<BaseResourceModel>>(Base: B) => {
    new (...args: any[]): TableMixin<BaseResourceModel>.(Anonymous function)<B>.Temporary;
    prototype: TableMixin<...>.(Anonymous function)<...>.Temporary;
} & B */
```

which is a function that takes a class constructor and returns another class constructor.  So you can give it `DummyBaseList` (and not anything like `DummyBaseList<T>`):

```
const TMBRMDBL = TMBRM(DummyBaseList);
/*const TMBRMDBL: {
    new (...args: any[]): TableMixin<BaseResourceModel>.
       (Anonymous function)<typeof DummyBaseList>.Temporary;
    prototype: TableMixin<...>.(Anonymous function)<...>.Temporary;
} & typeof DummyBaseList */
```

So that is a class constructor.  It seems to be a generic class constructor because its type is also assignable `typeof DummyBaseList`, so we should be able to extend it with a type parameter:

```
class BST<T> extends TMBRMDBL<T> { } // okay
```

It's a bit of a tricky thing in TypeScript; normally a generic class *constructor value* (like `Array`) cannot be given a generic type parameter (saying `const foo = Array<string>` is an error); it's only the generic class *interface type* that can do that (so `const bar: Array<string>` is okay).  But when you extend a generic class, you *do* put a type parameter after the constructor name (like `class Foo extends Array<string> { }`.

---

So that's how you get the code to compile without syntax errors.

Note that I have absolutely no idea if this behaves how you want, since it's full of angular-specific and other functionality that I'm not an expert in.  For all I know, the next thing you try to do after this will break horribly... but for the question as asked, that's the answer.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgeQHYElXBgGhagEQFMBnGKCATzwGEJwJUjV4BfOAMwpDgHIABAIaoA5gFcANoKgB6AMbQivAFDKiAD0iw4ggEZkogufDlSSJOACFBJIgCVSEMVDlEAshAAmRCYmVwAuDAxXQlgOThgTwB+AC44A2BRAG5lVlUYSjAiODpUOSgiGCIaMxIAHhoAPjgAXjgmAHc4AAoAOg7pERJ44UoAbQBdAEo6mppUtU1oeCTiqA4jHPRrWwAZYDJygBU4DWLUTwtV+0dnVw9vCSr-QP3mI9zGAqKSsvKTja3tqpqENNUGi08A4YnyMGAjDg2z0EncwHUSR2e3UB0eJwcJCcLncXh8VRao3+gTghRgzlQnDBxkhlI+KLRFhWNiIXxgO1+LRO8UsRNuJICphsFm2RAYhiglAZD2OLMi4DhIGYMAsaEw2D8AsC6S1ATJFOhYq00koqRJrFS6WU-DoDCYLBaSGKCsExXivF4cFYwymwJ0+nIRhMZSsLLZyPuh1ltkx2IueOu-PlYEVytVGCwuHwxAMVD8AOttsg9pgjrgzpTrqI7s93t9M39BiDcCF5lDtgAykQoAA3bvh3aR9Es2PnXFXGpD6Oszbsn75q0KVBkaFuSx2Nx1aGw+GI1AfEdnHGXfGE1IyABULcYK+2a438XpU7gzPWs4PMaP8YnBO5VlGtR-EmTStB0bRdD0OioAMIzxDCoS7kiGJfuO+JtC0ACCqCMJQIBOBYoLgrSwwfFUbSiuKJpmoEYAUDAECZNkcE7m4CJImBZGYdh0F4WIBHUhCjAkRx5FGtAVFpHAABkVhwBeMiqK2FgEGIIAgJQnzvvOz6ad8fxeopN7wHe65uAQlhrFuJkbi0KlqRpYazsM54Xkut73mZFnxMSgQge0nRQN0vTQUMwzMQhrF7h+pxYmOJ7XOhWE4bx-FEUJ5SMUQEAcHAdnqbpMBkRRxqStRAS0QxDFZNW24RWx+4iVxyX4VSaWoMJHRFWJEqmpJMmZdluWqfljkrvJqjKEpVgdtsHLSlGq6meZaxzUg7AyDIcAQAA1oIlCKSGJxdr23bwXCc1TkmLRnYh+7IbFx4JgSwy2cNDlvmQwwkfOa1AA)

Comment: wow for even attempting to answer the q +1

Comment: Thank you @jcalz, worked perfectly. By the way, is there a way to remove the class ```DummyBaseList```?