# Passing generic types to mixins in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

TLDR: I just want incrementally grow generic type through extending and also with mixins (problem was doing it with mixins).

I already found [Passing generic types through to mixins in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492002/passing-generic-types-through-to-mixins-in-typescript), but i can not make it work for my use case.

Basically I need to have "data" of AbstractEntity dynamic with possibility to change existing attributes types. This is achieved with "Modify". I change types of data with appending new attributes with every new Entity. This all works with T1, T2, T3, but with mixins, i somehow can not achieve same behaviour.

Example:

```js
type Modify<T, R> = Omit<T, keyof R> & R;
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

interface AbstractEntityType {
    value?: number | string | boolean | Date
}

interface EntityType {
    value?: string | number
    name?: string
}

interface EntityAnotherType {
    value?: number
    another?: number
}

class AbstractEntity<T = {}> {
    public data!: Modify<AbstractEntityType & T, T>;

    getData() {
        return this.data || {};
    }

    setData(data: Modify<AbstractEntityType & T, T>) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class Entity<T = {}> extends AbstractEntity<Modify<EntityType & T, T>> {
    entityMethod() {}
}

const T1 = new AbstractEntity();
const T2 = new Entity();
const T3 = new Entity<EntityAnotherType>(); // There is possible modification

T1.getData().value; // expected type (ok): string | number | boolean | Date | undefined

T2.getData().value; // expected type (ok): string | number | undefined
T2.getData().name; // expected type (ok): string | undefined

T3.getData().value; // expected type (ok): number | undefined
T3.getData().another; // expected type (ok): number | undefined
T3.getData().name; // expected type (ok): string | undefined

// works until I use mixin

interface EntityMixedType {
    mixed?: boolean
}

function mixin<D extends Constructor<AbstractEntity<EntityMixedType>>>(baseClass: D) {
    class Mixed extends baseClass {
        isMixed() {
            return this.getData().mixed;
        }

        someMethod() {
            return this.getData().value;
        }
    }

    return Mixed;
}

class EntityMixed<T = {}> extends mixin<typeof Entity>(Entity)<T> {
    someOtherMethod() {}
}

const T4 = new EntityMixed();

T4.getData().mixed; // expected type (ok): boolean | undefined
T4.isMixed(); // expected type (ok): boolean | undefined
T4.entityMethod(); // method exists - OK
T4.someOtherMethod(); // method exists - OK
T4.someMethod(); // NOK - should be: string | number | undefined
T4.getData().name // NOK, even if I pass Entity to mixin

const T5 = new EntityMixed<EntityAnotherType>();
T5.getData().another; // NOK
```

Problem is, that T4 loses type information of Entity, which i extend and is seems it only knows AbstractEntity (D extends Constructor<AbstractEntity>).

Also it ignores type modification with T5, which adds "another" to "data".

Is it possible to do that with mixins? I mean last lines with NOK comment.

**EDIT**:
I added playground and a code a bit, this is what i found so far.
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwJYDMQB4AqAaKAlAPigF4oB5AWyWC1wGsIQ4V8iAyfAbgFgAoUSFADCcAHYBnYACcArgGNgcKVhJQA3gF8ipURADuUABQA6UwEMpAc3EAuKGdEgA2gF0AlCSKYevPklHAEFIoZnLQAIIARpJSocAAogHUIJjg0Gp8UFlQAG5mADYyEAD8dqIyFJFBUAA%20UDH%20lrVQkXBw%20RAOzQAiZoF8Gnx%20AUEhYVCJwMmpghm82bkFRaX10o3N5ZVBmdmiZhQldg2ilgNDvP6BwaHQk8nhonDAABZBM%20k7WXmFh1CbVVJPvZHi8git-tteINfLw5PkzOJxFAojE4ndQCpSJoiHMFmAZJF8kg5FAEH0zABCOzwZBodAo6RopKgd5QDg4KCYAg%20IGWCDAXrAMyGDy4hbZKT8mRSURQF5IcTGMlC2p1TQ%20BbQoHifmC4XKszUxCoDAM2IKdEpNJszm4LmioELeWKg2qA0a7LQrWw%20GIibMjCYVTYqAQAAegVECCRZqZUwxNJN6EtrPZdoIOKBEADMH5z0QIvUXvOcjEkk5AEZVLoDLGLQGRT5SxJgJyAEzV-T%20%20MgRt8ZvlzAAZk7BktyYDDyeryk7wIjagAHpF5yZ9AFVAwHBEUhCdAKMaUMS%20kgxOdMBXjHyBeSRcZvkVOEuV%20HIAoIAg5dbDHA6G4jmsJwbBUALNK07SdLKdSCtAdQyFGEBHroCDnm2V66rebj3ksEBPsuoZhm%20gSfgI0A-n%20AFSOsdQQlIzTwQgiH%20B%20fCYGh156neewHHhL6ERA74kd%20v7-qsVFAXBCFISxMLDuhN5CneD64c%20BFER%20X6CORom0fRUnMShvByRxmHGA405BLxakCcRmlkSJZQgdUkmMdJhnGRhilYdxKn4a%20NkaaRRgOWJ1FQAxTHIec%20F6EodBIvBUz5FAACS4U6lAVBhv45yXKMNzdskMBIGGH6smKWRZR%20KzgR0DhnDCKDwQop6yll-joN0BGRtGwhltI8iKModYJAGE49sVpUIHOGaGJECIQEIvq2FA3QOvM2RwgiSKTRp4Y9Ui806kt23qI62QKrtCCFhV4oLJKwDSrKzryZxWFVQgHp3d6d1ZOIcAHLmLwFutv3ig9T1ys8CqvaZylfeK0Kauc91SjKsAlR%20PjeltfqWldmJFkQ%203Zr17WiOgpHMIVoDzpabhYJmG1-QDEBkKCUhA-m12isWMIDq2mAACyjjTIBXX2slC7DXnGB9Vn%20YJdnBRRLRtHVUHhfpUVGdLl2YzzCv8UrQXaXYtWQXprkGax0vZhNeYg1ZBzA5%204YKsASIALTkAA0rbxj-Qc7MzlzTuqS73MER73t%20wHQcQGHhuqQAcmQvtQD74j5jI%20SflUlFhbpLmRTJwsy8K3n7NA%20Fp77uAQDk2ZQKgqWbqdlpynAmUlTl-P9ZyACsov4wb433CCM5zpLmCDxXd7mRznBAA)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NBjzVN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: It was actually code pasted from my editor, but I also created TS playground. Link in edit. I modified it a bit, but i still cannot solve my problem.

Comment: Hmm, I really doubt that you can do what you want with all those generic type parameters in the face of mixins, but I'm not sure.  Right now the example is a bit too complicated for me to follow properly so I'll probably bow out; hopefully someone else has more insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple attempt, I figured it out, not 100% ok, but I can work with that. [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwJYDMQB4AqAaKAlAPigF4oB5AWyWC1wGsIQ4V8iAyfAbgFgAoUSFADCcAHYBnYACcArgGNgcKVhJQA3gF8ipURADuUABQA6UwEMpAc3EAuKGdEgA2gF0AlCSKYevPklHAEFIoZnLQAIIARpJSocAAogHUIJjg0Gp8UFlQAG5mADYyEAD8dqIyFJFBUAA%20UDH%20lrVQkXBw%20RAOzQAiZoF8Gnx%20AUEhYVCJwMmpghm82bkFRaX10o3N5ZVBmdmiZhQldg2ilgNDvP6BwaHQk8nhonDAABZBM%20k7WXmFh1CbVVJPvZHi8git-tteINfLw5PkzOJxFAojE4ndQCpSJoiHMFmAZJF8kg5FAEH0zABCOzwZBodAo6RopKgd5QDg4KCYAg%20IGWCDAXrAMyGDy4hbZKT8mRSURQF5IcTGMlC2p1QyaexIgQQZhy54KpXktw%20BbQoHifmC4XKszUxCoDAM2IKdEpNJszm4LmioELeWKm2qG0m7LQs2w%20GIibMjCYVTYqAQAAegVECCRTqZUwxNId6FdrPZXoIOKBEBjMH5z0QIvUYfOcjEkk5AEZVLoDJmXTGRT5GxJgJyAEzt-TR7MgXt8fvNzAAZlHBld%20ZjDyeryk7wIvagAHpd5yN9AFVAwHBEUhCdAKPaUMS%20kgxOdMC3jHyBeSRcZvkVOHuD8mkAKBACByu6hhwHQbhHGsJwbBUALNK07SdLKdSCtAdQyGmEB3roCDPkOb6Wp%20bjfksEB-vuiZJkBgSgdqRiQdBqxSOsdQQlIzTYQguH%20CBfCYER75Wl%20ewHFRAG0RAwEMeBzEwWxcFYTheECTC87ER%20Qpfj%20lH-jRdEgWBggQVBZQIdUKm8WpBG8JpImkcYDjrkEkmGTJ9EmdAZksZx3GqfxdkOSROlkeJ%20nUYBnnGYxvmKexUA8Xx%20HnNRehKHQSLYVM%20RQAAkklFpQFQSb%20OclyjDc47JDASBJiBrJilkpUgSsyEdA4ZwXCM1zjK6iRmFeCBNWWezDe1bSdaI3V8Cg2EKI%20sqlf46DdDRqbpsITbSPIijKF2CQxiuE51Q1I1pCW26RAiEBCJGthQN0PrzNkcIIkiZ3Gcmm1IjdFr3R96i%20tkCpfQgtbNeKCySsA0qyv6WmiWRrUICG0PhtDWTiHAByVi8NYvVj4qw-DeoGo5YXkT86PitCprnDDUoyrA9XGQiRjrRw2q6uDbizbw82iItYglfV-iDcNa0beWW0iAOsgKEo9LRIy3YTidySSx0F2QFdhj-XdD12M9wOvVk71RuDMtpn9t2A1GUMLAq2sgZDIPQ6TLOI5TwpkeWQ067TDPm1AmMSszsrWxzhhc95vNswg-NQg2D01aA4OYnWRA-bLSIraIhium4KgcK64NbmbCw4wcZCglI%20PVhDor1jCM6DpgAAsi7pyA4NThpndI05ek%20F3w9U6j7nRbJ3lMeZLRTahAU2UFglD2Dic7lF0mz3FCmLyhXTWSl6nj%20Wp1VoT7kHAToHJgqwBIgAtOQADS6-GDXEB1xujfXwZW%20TcaKPxfu-T%2039-7N3cgAOSeJqDyslcCMV1HpKAJ4UBSFxsiVWzojoTnQQOTooFdSulwJEGQg5CpyC6ESHI0A9DUGeHqPon9fZiX2JFA8cCDAnjIG-KAr9jhNBPrZBsO1OQAFYe7l0TprUAa565bgHpgSRE8-bORBBuWBcBeFIn4YIv4lkuKiLXjCSqfVoAwDMP4UaocIDiBoZASaR8Zqh1clIFYGEBaW0%20jY0Qy44ykGsbYy6NstoF1dhDWR50S5xjLjGKJlcoaBEkO7UOTM4be31IqdhxogStz4B2WA-jXRfhduNHWvYgA)

Returned class in mixin has to be retyped with "return Mixed as (D & typeof Mixed)" and also I have to put type EntityMixed twice - in mixin declaration and while extending.

```js
type Modify<T, R> = Omit<T, keyof R> & R;
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

interface AbstractEntityType {
    value?: number | string | boolean | Date
}

interface EntityType {
    value?: string | number
    name?: string
}

interface EntityAnotherType {
    value?: number
    another?: number
}

class AbstractEntity<T = {}> {
    public data!: Modify<AbstractEntityType & T, T>;

    getData() {
        return this.data || ({} as typeof this.data);
    }

    setData(data: Modify<AbstractEntityType & T, T>) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class Entity<T = {}> extends AbstractEntity<Modify<EntityType & T, T>> {
    entityMethod() {}
}

const T1 = new AbstractEntity();
const T2 = new Entity();
const T3 = new Entity<EntityAnotherType>(); // There is possible modification

T1.getData().value; // expected type (ok): string | number | boolean | Date | undefined

T2.getData().value; // expected type (ok): string | number | undefined
T2.getData().name; // expected type (ok): string | undefined

T3.getData().value; // expected type (ok): number | undefined
T3.getData().another; // expected type (ok): number | undefined
T3.getData().name; // expected type (ok): string | undefined

// works until I use mixin

interface EntityMixedType {
    mixed?: boolean
}
interface EntityEnabledType {
    enabled?: boolean
}

function mixin<D extends Constructor<AbstractEntity<EntityMixedType>>>(baseClass: D) {
    class Mixed extends baseClass {
        isMixed() {
            return this.getData().mixed;
        }

        someMethod() {
            return this.getData().value;
        }
    }

    return Mixed as (D & typeof Mixed)
}

function mixinEnabled<D extends Constructor<AbstractEntity<EntityEnabledType>>>(baseClass: D) {
    class Mixed extends baseClass {
        isEnabled() {
            return this.getData().enabled;
        }
    }

    return Mixed as (D & typeof Mixed)
}

class EntityMixed<T = {}> extends mixin(Entity)<T & EntityMixedType> {
    someOtherMethod() {}
}

const T4 = new EntityMixed();

T4.getData().value;
T4.getData().mixed; // expected type (ok): boolean | undefined
T4.isMixed(); // expected type (ok): boolean | undefined
T4.entityMethod(); // method exists - OK
T4.someOtherMethod(); // method exists - OK
T4.someMethod(); // Not as expected, type of value is from AbstractEntity instead of Entity, but I can live with that
T4.getData().name; // Now is OK - string | undefined

const T5 = new EntityMixed<EntityAnotherType>();
T5.getData().another; // Now is OK - number | undefined

interface MainType {
    escape?: boolean
    other?: Date
}

class MainEntity<T = MainType> extends mixinEnabled(EntityMixed)<T & EntityEnabledType> {
    test() {
        return this.getData();
    }
}

new MainEntity().isEnabled();
```