# Passing generic types through mixin functions in TypeScript and resolving concrete types later

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to use TypeScript mixins with generic types in a way which I believe is different to the closely related questions [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48492002/13352657) and [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70815366/13352657). In this case:

1. The classes the mixins are being applied to are generic - so the solution of [Q1 "Passing generic types through to mixins in Typescript"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48492205/13352657) doesn't apply because it relies on resolving all generics in `TaggedBroker` before applying the mixin to it
2. The data the mixin functions are operating on is also generic - but it's not direct properties of the class being mixed like it seems to be in [Q2 "Passing generic types to mixins in Typescript"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70848274/13352657)

Consider the below simplified example, also available [**here on TypeScript Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqAfFALxQIQDuUAFAHSMCGqA5kgFxRMIgDaAXQCUZEgQDcAWABQMgJYJgEVADMmmaAEkAQugAmekFADeMqFAAWPVgHl0wWkK4AjOHAA2EHlOkBfGTKY7kxISFAACspIiIS6BkYQAB5KCHphOvqGJKbS5s4QKHGGXARFID7mmIgoGNi4tM76JWUixlDAFnJI9PmFmUbkjXriUP5+AdIq6AjYcohQAMpwmHJM7gCycokKsSHQSSlpsNVoWDj4kajRCLH9REQANFCl-VAHEKnpZUS0C+iQqBgwVCzT2rTMUFQEGA6FQCCgQRCYSWKzWb2SHyOfwBQKRJgh5iQ6FYrAKwAAYqg5JikI5mv1BCZIdDYfC+B0uj0yWUBCMxuYxmNAsCwjYVCo5BoAOq4ADWylu8XRhy+d2VNIiURiL3i2TGAHp9VAAILAdoWaBgOAKM1UaCUCB6dpwbhgMDuIwdaAAWy2CiedqgKDk7ncUD0iAA5GbZQg4DQvVAJQg0TrDO1wBAOMK8SjVu4xRLpXKFWmEhjPlAMrr1ZW82tNtsELRC5KIDLUPLUEJFVkTELpIjQlAAOJuPRlKByb3uiDej7AVVKnKE-5W1CLrg1BSsQQVBEnWrnRxMjndIlu3CLshQPgAIjvvNGEKsCFs9hPbShMLh7QwED5GQByHMJtCYCdXmnWd50UJd0xXcNUCYb0mC3NAd33KpkFOOpUE-c1OT0JCUJvB9ANySxrDsBxWmZH94TUdwkAA59xlkaRDSgOxUEWZZ81bYtO2UKAACpmLnJARKgUlKCpTBnWeMonkaM0ugQaMoAAR3QOQlCgKg5R3bgwiSSBsEdRh6BzYcAAkmDdEABPbEsePeOs+LWJyOy7PAxzgCCawQs9vKQGxZU-AkCO6XpgDKegL3XRcRigTiADkXTAVA4GcTxvTCC0oQhQUJhAqAABlEAgD0vJc2ssQ8gtxTbbyFTAgK+yCzokG0KEmFlWlwQo8xOIAUQAJTGmwxqgABaKB8kwJh0GYoNiVJFBKWpT4Ty6P8vCUJ0QirMpGQUFAvCdOAVCgNqToESKz3itayU2mlHD4AAGAR6CI5CmH3YrpCAA):

```js
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

interface IBuddy {
  hangOut(): boolean;
}

class Person<TBuddy extends IBuddy> {
  bestBuddy: TBuddy;
  constructor(bud: TBuddy) { this.bestBuddy = bud; }
}

function SocialMixin<TBase extends Constructor<Person<TBuddy>>, TBuddy extends IBuddy>(SuperClass: TBase) {
  return class Social extends SuperClass {
    suggestFriends(): TBuddy[] { return [this.bestBuddy]; }
  }
}

class OfficeWorker<TBuddy extends IBuddy> extends Person<TBuddy> {}
// At the point we need to apply the mixin, we still don't know the final TBuddy type:
class SocialOfficeWorker<TBuddy extends IBuddy> extends SocialMixin(OfficeWorker)<TBuddy> {}
```

Now we have a `SocialOfficeWorker` that **seems** to be generic to `TBuddy`, but it doesn't quite behave as expected:

```js
class GoodBuddy implements IBuddy {
  supports: string[];
  constructor() { this.supports = [""]; }
  hangOut() { return true; }
}

class BadBuddy implements IBuddy {
  drama: string;
  constructor() { this.drama = ""; }
  hangOut() { return false; }
}

class HappyOfficeWorker extends SocialOfficeWorker<GoodBuddy> {
  thisWorksOk() {
    this.bestBuddy.supports;  // No problems here
  }
}

class LonelyOfficeWorker extends SocialOfficeWorker<BadBuddy> {
  thisBreaks() {
    // ERROR - because suggestFriends() is treated as IBuddy[] instead of BadBuddy[]
    this.suggestFriends()[0].drama;
  }
}
```

I didn't get any success from casting the return type of mixin `SocialMixin` as Q2 suggested. Is there any way to write mixin functions operating on generic types, and then resolve those types **after** applying the mixin to a generic class?

Comment: I strongly suspect that without direct support for higher kinded types (see [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)) or related features like [ms/TS#36406](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36406), this isn't possible.  I could imagine changing your whole approach to use factory functions instead of classes, but I believe the answer to the question is "no, sorry".  I won't write up such an answer unless it becomes clear that nobody else has any clever approach that achieves the same thing.  Good luck!