# Can TypeScript mixins add generic functions (to separately-generic classes)?

Tags: typescript, generics

I'd like to define some mixin functionality (i.e. the standard [TypeScript mixins pattern](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html)) based on *generic data structures* that have known interfaces but will be fully finalized later.

Many of the base classes I'd like to apply them to *also* have some generic aspects.

It seems perfectly possible to apply non-generic mixins to generic classes, for example the below where `WithHouse` is fully specified up-front and `Pet` takes a `TFavoriteToy` argument:

```js
class Dog<TFavoriteToy extends object> extends WithHouse(Pet)<TFavoriteToy> {}
```

...But in the case where the mixin needs **its own type parameterization**, I can't find any way to apply it except in cases where I'm ready to fully specify all type arguments already.

Consider the following brief example:

```js
/**
 * Abstract base class with partial implementation
 */
export class BaseThing<TData extends object> {
  dataSource: TData;
  constructor(data: TData) {
    this.dataSource = data;
  }
}

type Constructor<T> = (new (...args: any[]) => T);

/**
 * A mixin with generic-ified functionality
 */
export function WithCustomer<
  T extends Constructor<{}>,
  TCustomer extends {name: string}
>(SuperClass: T) {
  return class extends SuperClass {
    _cnames: string[];
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
      this._cnames = [];
    }
    logCustomer(customer: TCustomer): TCustomer {
      this._cnames.push(customer.name);
      return customer;
    }
  };
}

// Imagine concrete instances of TData and TCustomer:
type TActualData = {count: number};
type TActualCust = {name: string; phone: string};

/**
 * It seems okay to apply the mixin *after* fulfilling all type args in both
 * base and mixin:
 */
export class WorkingThing extends WithCustomer<
  Constructor<BaseThing<TActualData>>,
  TActualCust
>(BaseThing) {
  constructor(data: TActualData) {
    super(data);
    this.logCustomer({name: 'Joe', phone: '123'});
  }
}

/**
 * The problem class: Applying the mixin without resolving the underlying
 * generics... Error: "No base constructor has the specified number of type
 * arguments. ts(2508)"
 */
export class BrokenThing<TData, TCustomer>
  extends WithCustomer(BaseThing)<TData, TCustomer>
{
  // (Aim to implement extra features that are still generic to some extent)
}
```

I've tried various locations for the type annotations in the `extends` expression, but haven't found a way to get it working. Even in the seemingly-simpler case where we'd be okay to solidify `BaseThing<TActualData>` as the base class first, before applying the mixin, I can't see a solution?

So far it seems like it might just not be possible to implement type-generic functionality in a mixin... But I can't see why that should be from a prototype chain perspective, and would love if there's just some syntactic tweak I'm missing!

Comment: You have to update the mix-in class returned to accept the generics, since with this notation `withCustomer()<GenericHere>` you are applying generic to the returned thing by the function, which is a class that doesn't accept generic arguments.
`return class<U, V> extends SuperClass {}`. Note that you will start getting an error `A mixin class must have a constructor with a single rest parameter of type 'any[]'`, which is happening when the mix-in accepts a generic argument and the base class also a generic class. I'm not sure if there is a bug ticket for it.

Comment: TS doesn't want to let you put generics in the scopes necessary for this to work; I think you can try to force an ad-hoc workaround by using type assertions like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1Lg8W) maybe (although, I don't know if that actually behaves how you want so you should test it). Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz but I think there are still significant problems with your playground's `BrokenThing`: The `.dataSource` and `.logCustomer()` properties aren't recognised on a `new` instance of it, and also can't access these properties within the body of `BrokenThing` to define methods/etc that process them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found so far for this (from [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48492205/13352657)) works only in cases where we're able to resolve the generics *introduced by* the mixin, *at the point where the mixin is applied*:

```
export function buildWithCustomer<TCustomer extends {name: string}>() {
  return function WithCustomer<T extends Constructor<{}>>(SuperClass: T) {
    return class extends SuperClass {
      _cnames: string[];
      constructor(...args: any[]) {
        super(...args);
        this._cnames = [];
      }
      logCustomer(customer: TCustomer): TCustomer {
        this._cnames.push(customer.name);
        return customer;
      }
    };
  };
}

// TActualCust must be concrete (cannot be an argument to WorkaroundThing)
export class WorkaroundThing<TData extends { count: 2 }>
  extends buildWithCustomer<TActualCust>()(BaseThing)<TData> {
  constructor(data: TData) {
    super(data);
    // Can access defined properties from both base class and mixin:
    for (let i = 0; i < this.dataSource.count; ++i) {
      this.logCustomer({name: 'Joe', phone: '123'});
    }
  }
}
```

Interestingly it seems like the opposite pattern (to resolve the base class generics but keep the new ones at the point of mixin application) does **not** work:

```js
export function buildWithCustomer2<T extends Constructor<{}>>(SuperClass: T) {
  return function WithCustomer<TCustomer extends {name: string}>() {
    // (Implementation as above)
  };
}

// No base constructor has the specified number of type arguments.ts(2508)
// (expected 1, got 0)
export class WorkaroundThing2<TCustomer extends TActualCust>
  extends buildWithCustomer<TActualData>(BaseThing)()<TCustomer> {
  // ...
}
```

As far as I can tell it's probably not possible to achieve the full general case of applying a generic mixin functionality to a generic base class, without resolving either set of type arguments yet - but would love to be wrong.